# node + TypeScript: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'events'

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm in the process of converting a Node + ES6 project to TypeScript. I'm aiming for ES6 (as I'm running Node 7.x) and using Map.

Running `tsc -p` returns:

- `src/actions.ts(3,9): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'events'`
- `src/calendar.ts(5,10): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'fetchEvents'.`
- `src/index.ts(3,5): error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'actions' must be of type 'Map<any, any>', but here has type 'any'.`

It's not clear why these are duplicate identifiers or are being tagged as re-declared, particularly in the context of Node's require/module imports. Using the standard `const` in a require statement broke this more severely.

**calendar.ts**

```
const { rp } = require("request-promise")

var events = <any> {}

// both are exported via module.exports = { events, fetchEvents }
function fetchEvents(key: string, url: string, options: object) {
    ...
```

**actions.ts**

```
const moment = require("moment")
var { events, fetchEvents } = require("./calendar")

var actions = new Map()
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "./built",
    "declaration": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "baseUrl" : "./packages",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "dist",
    "node_modules",
    ".vscode"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the `var {...` construction is valid. `var` makes the variable scoped kind of globally.

What if You use in **actions.ts**:

```
const moment = require("moment")
import calendar = require("./calendar");
// console.log(calendar.events)
```

?

Comment: This works, because TypeScript appears to handle imports/namespaces differently. I could not find good documentation on this, but using `module.exports = { events, fetchEvents }` and then subsequently importing as `calendar` works.